# MongoDB does Birt support aggregate cursor

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, birt

When I use Mongodb aggregation with Birt I had the error below:

```
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: 
Unable to run the Aggregate command operation.
Check that your connected MongoDB server is version 2.2 or later. ;
    com.mongodb.CommandResult$CommandFailure: command failed [aggregate]: 
{ "serverUsed" : "/xxx.xx.xx.xxx:27017" , 
  "errmsg" : "exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)" , 
  "code" : 16389 , "ok" : 0.0 , 
  "$gleStats" : { "lastOpTime" : { "$ts" : 0 , "$inc" : 0} , 
  "electionId" : { "$oid" : "557cd07784d145278edfba15"}}}
```

Comment: What Version is your MongoDB server?
Have you tried to search for the Error Code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run aggregate MongoDB queries. Check the MongoDB version.